# Build failing with Google Play Services Plugin. Could not find com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to build my app for android. I currently have the Google AdMob package installed as well as the Google Play Services plugin however it is failing to build with the google play services package.

```
> Could not find com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/games/gpgs-plugin-support/0.11.01/gpgs-plugin-support-0.11.01.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/games/gpgs-plugin-support/0.11.01/gpgs-plugin-support-0.11.01.pom
       - file:PROJECT_FOLDER/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/gpgs-plugin-support-0.11.01.jar
       - file:PROJECT_FOLDER/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/gpgs-plugin-support.jar
```

I already have the location set correctly in

`Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dependencies>
<!-- Internal library dependency generated at build time. 
    It also defines the transitive dependencies on play-services
-->
  <androidPackages>
    <androidPackage spec="com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01">
      <repositories>
        <repository>Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository</repository>
      </repositories>
    </androidPackage>
  </androidPackages>
</dependencies>
```

I have done multiple force resolves, I have changed the JAVA_HOME environment variable. I am at a complete loss as to what is causing this issue and I suspect it's something to do with the admob package and Google Play Services conflicting.

Here is my `Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle` file to help too:

```
// Android Resolver Repos Start
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = $/file:///**DIR_UNITYPROJECT**/$.replace("\\", "/")
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/" // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7, Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleUmpDependencies.xml:7
        }
        maven {
            url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository") // Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml:11
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.1.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleUmpDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01' // Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml:11
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi-v7a/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    ndkPath "**NDKPATH**"

    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = **BUILTIN_NOCOMPRESS** + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
}
**IL_CPP_BUILD_SETUP**
**SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download both packages: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/current-build/GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.11.01.unitypackage and https://github.com/google/play-unity-plugins/releases/download/v1.8.0/com.google.play.appupdate-1.8.0.unitypackage.
2. Create a new 2D project with Unity 2020.3.30f1
3. Switch plateform to Android
4. Import GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.11.01.unitypackage with Assets/Import package/Custom package/GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.11.01.unitypackage
5. Auto resolution popup appears: Enable
6. Resolving Android Dependencies appears: 100% resolved
7. Check if plugin is installed by looking at Windows/Google Play Games
8. Import com.google.play.appupdate-1.8.0.unitypackage
9. Resolving Android Dependencies appears: Library processing complete
10. Error appears: Resolution failed and another popup appears: Google Version Handler: Would you like to delete obsolete EDM 1.2.169 ? --> apply
    You can repeat 9-10 infinitly by force resolving Assets/ EDM/Android Resolver/Force resolve

Comment: I have tried with this but I am still getting the same error, Force Resolve doesn't seem to fix my issue.

Comment: I use GPGS v0.11.01 and was same error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGames.
Android Force Resolve failed with an error Failed to fetch the following dependencies: com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:+.
How did I fix it:

open the file Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml
change line Packages/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository to Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository
run Android Force Resolve

Comment: The line in GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml had already been changed to  Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository before the original error

Comment: * open the file Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml

* change line `Packages/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository` to `Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository`

* run Android Force Resolve

This solved my issue. The line in my GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml was pointing to the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8ynwRd8Uxc

1. Open file:  **Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml**
2. Find the following line

   `<repository>Packages/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository</repository>`
3. Replace it with:

   `<repository>Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository</repository>`
4. Save and close file
5. On Unity, click menu **Assets** -> **External Dependency Manager** -> **Android Resolver** -> **Force Resolve**

Comment: Hi Tony. Editors are noted clearly in each post. You can see your profile card is marked as "answered" (since you wrote it) and mine is "edited" (since I amended it).

Comment: Mutual editing is very normal here. It is expected that new users are willing to have their posts edited.

Comment: Religious and political and other remarks not connected with the subject of programming tend to be removed. We also remove meta-material relating to voting, editing, commenting, etc. This is part of the curation process, and helps us maintain a quality resource.